# HTML snippet within Zend_Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm using `Zend_Form` as part of a simple signup process. In part 1 of 2 the user is able to upload a number of images. In part 2 - for each one of these images - I ask the user to add further details - an additional 4 text fields grouped together using `addDisplayGroup`. Within each display group I want to display a thumbnail of the uploaded image. I have generated these thumbs and all the processing is complete but i'm unsure what the best approach is for displaying the image within the relevant section. I guess its possible to create a custom form element to display this but somehow this feels like overkill considering the image is purely being used for display purposes. I also dont really want to replace `$this->form->render()` with a manual outputting of the form. Could this be achieved with a decorator maybe? I'm still fairly new to ZF so any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a custom decorator in your decorator stack for the display group. Or you could use the HtmlTag decorator.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.displaygroups

Answer (score 1):

there is an excelent example for an Custom image "Preview" Element:

[Zend Form with Image](http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/content/custom-zend-form-image-upload-element)

Or try the Zend_Form_Element_Image shipped with the Framework

[Zend Form Element Image](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.Image)

Comment: hi, i think you have misunderstood me slightly. maybe i wasnt clear enough. Your solutions are both for using images as part of a form, what i need is to display images within the form but they are not actual form elements.